# Make screen stable when element is expanding CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the issue on a website, which is a webstore: on mobile, there's a filter overlay with expandable categories containing filter options (e.g. brands, colour, size). When expanded, they have a list of checkbox-filters. When filters are selected, a new `div` appears for "selected Filters section", and all further selected filters are added there.

The thing is, the filters list is quite long, and anytime I choose a new filter somewhere deep down, the screen moves a bit down, because the "Selected filters" div is added with a new element. I need to make sure that when "selected filters" field is out of sight, its expansion won't make the screen move.

I tried various ways with `position: relative` and `position: sticky`, it didn't work as expected. How can I achieve this?

### DEMO:

```css
.FilterOverlay {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.SelectedFilters {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-family: inherit;
    outline: 0;
}
.FiltersAttributes {
    --option-margin: .5rem;
}
.ExpandableFilterCategory {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    font-family: inherit;
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="FilterOverlay">
    <div class="SelectedFilters"> *applied filters render here* </div>
    <div class="FiltersAttributes">
        <div class="ExpandableFilterCategory"> *checkboxes*</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible make the "selected Filters section" scrollable?

Comment: I'd like it to be like this, since making it scrollable will not be "beautiful"

Comment: Maybe find the height of the `div` at the top with `offsetHeight` then move the page back up with `window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY + div.offsetHeight())`?

Comment: Is it css-possible, or do I have to apply JS? And to which ```div``` should I apply this - "FiltersAttributes" or "ExpandableFilterCategory"?

Comment: I don't think it is css-possible.